# Mysql Insert Ignore.. On duplicate key update causes Deadlock

Tags: mysql, sql-update, deadlock, bulkinsert

I am using Mysql version 5.7, When i used inserting bulk data into table using insert ignore.. on duplicate key update. If same record found then time will be updated.
Below is my table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `unauthuserpostview` (
    `postid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `serial` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `createdat` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_unauthuserpostview_postid_serial` (`postid`,`serial`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Below is my bulk insert query.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO unauthuserpostview(postid,serial) VALUES ( 44654, 'qpmpf' ),( 44653, 'qpmpf' ),( 44652, 'qpmpf' ),( 44651, 'qpmpf' ),( 44650, 'qpmpf' ),( 44649, 'qpmpf' ),( 44648, 'qpmpf' ),( 44647,             'qpmpf' ),( 44646, 'qpmpf' ),( 44645, 'qpmpf' )on duplicate key update createdat = now()
```

Query is working properly but sometime it causes deadlock. Why sometime it cause deadlock and how to solve this?
And for better performance i am using bulk insert.
Below is deadlock result :-

```
 LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
    ------------------------
    2018-12-08 08:36:10 0x7f3c5794c700
    *** (1) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 2488051, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
    MySQL thread id 65, OS thread handle 139897890834176, query id 12946 192.168.1.127 root update
     INSERT IGNORE INTO unauthuserpostview(postid,serial) VALUES ( 44654, 'qpmpf' ),( 44653, 'qpmpf' ),( 44652, 'qpmpf' ),( 44651, 'qpmpf' ),( 44650, 'qpmpf' ),( 44649, 'qpmpf' ),( 44648, 'qpmpf' ),( 44647,            'qpmpf' ),( 44646, 'qpmpf' ),( 44645, 'qpmpf' )on duplicate key update createdat = now()
    *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 422 page no 79 n bits 592 index idx_unauthuserpostview_postid_serial of table `development`.`unauthuserpostview` trx id 2488051 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention   waiting
    Record lock, heap no 491 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 8; hex 000000000000ae6e; asc        n;;
     1: len 5; hex 7172656d73; asc qrems;;
     2: len 6; hex 00000089bb9e; asc       ;;

    *** (2) TRANSACTION:
    TRANSACTION 2488045, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
    mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
    4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
    MySQL thread id 113, OS thread handle 139897144133376, query id 12936 192.168.1.127 root update
    INSERT IGNORE INTO unauthuserpostview(postid,serial) VALUES ( 44654, 'qfdvj' ),( 44653, 'qfdvj' ),( 44652, 'qfdvj' ),( 44651, 'qfdvj' ),( 44650, 'qfdvj' ),( 44649, 'qfdvj' ),( 44648, 'qfdvj' ),( 44647,             'qfdvj' ),( 44646, 'qfdvj' ),( 44645, 'qfdvj' )on duplicate key update createdat = now()
    *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
    RECORD LOCKS space id 422 page no 79 n bits 576 index idx_unauthuserpostview_postid_serial of table `development`.`unauthuserpostview` trx id 2488045 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
    Record lock, heap no 491 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 8; hex 000000000000ae6e; asc        n;;
     1: len 5; hex 7172656d73; asc qrems;;
     2: len 6; hex 00000089bb9e; asc       ;;

    *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 422 page no 79 n bits 592 index idx_unauthuserpostview_postid_serial of table `development`.`unauthuserpostview` trx id 2488045 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
    Record lock, heap no 491 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 8; hex 000000000000ae6e; asc        n;;
     1: len 5; hex 7172656d73; asc qrems;;
     2: len 6; hex 00000089bb9e; asc       ;;

    *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Below is my select query which is using frequently.

```
SELECT p.postid from postmst p  
left JOIN unauthuserpostview uv on p.postid = uv.postid and uv.serial 
= 'qpmpf' 
where uv.postid is NULL ORDER by p.postid desc LIMIT 50;
```

So my index is proper or not for above query?

Comment: Are you sure that these queries executed in autocommit mode and not inside transactions where other queries locking something? Also, look at this explanation: http://thushw.blogspot.com/2010/11/mysql-deadlocks-with-concurrent-inserts.html

Comment: @fifonik,yes this query executed in autocommit mode and when this query is executing that time no other query executing same table.

Comment: @5a01d01P Have you got any solution of it ?

Comment: @ManishGadhock No.

Comment: So what if another connection was updating the same table, it's no excuse. How naive is mysql's concurrency control? I'm going to try INSERT IGNORE everything and then look them all up with WHERE IN, and map the ids back. Hideous.